# Difficulty with ExternalEvaluate

Tags: syntax, external-calls, python

I am trying to import a Python function or execute a Python script from inside Mathematica, but the `ExternalEvaluate` command drives me nuts.
I proceed cautiously with the following Python test module, named "test.py":

```
def test():
   print("Test")
print("Hello")
```

I checked that the module can be found and tried it successfully from the CMD command line:

```
python
from test import test
```

Using `Import` in Mathematica also works:

```
Import["!python g:\\p\\python37\\test.py", "String"]
```

But then with `ExternalEvaluate` I first made sure that the Python connection works as follows, which works OK:

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "2+3"]
```

However, the following gives `Exception: Import Error. EvaluationFailure`:

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "from test import test"]
```

The same happens if I use a session:

```
ses = StartExternalSession["Python"]
ExternalEvaluate[ses, "from test import test"]
```

I would be glad for a hint what I am doing wrong

Comment: Check `os.getcwd()` and `sys.path`. `ExternalEvaluate` might not have those right to find it. Also check `sys.version` to make sure it's 3.7.

Comment: I checked this using ExternalEvaluate["Python","import os; print(os.getcwd())"] e.t.c. Everything o.k.

Comment: Heureka, after starting the PC and Mathematica  this morning, ExternalEvaluate seems to work. I am at a loss to explain this. Anyway, thank you for your effort.

Comment: My guess is that somehow the module wasn't on the python path or the wrong version of python was being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you start a session, `Working directory` in Windows, is `Documents` folder:

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "import os;os.getcwd()"]

(*Out: "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Documents" *)
```

### Import a single file

If you want to import a single file that does not import other files (not dependent on others), this solution will work:

```
ss = StartExternalSession["Python"];

ExternalEvaluate[ss, File["C:\\foo.py"]]

DeleteObject[ss];
```

Now it's like you had executed `from foo.py import *` and have access to all of its functions and variables.

### Import a file with its dependencies

If you have a file that imports other files, the above solution will raise an error:

```
File: C:\bar.py
===============

import foo

foo.test()
```

```
ss = StartExternalSession["Python"];

ExternalEvaluate[ss, File["C:\\bar.py"]]

DeleteObject[ss];
```

[image]

The solution is to make the file directory known to the python interpreter which have so many solutions (some discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)):

One of the solutions is to add `sys.path.append(...)` to the beginning of that file:

```
File: C:\bar.py
===============

import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\')

import foo

foo.test()
```

Now you have access to all of the functions and variables + ability to import other files.

All the code tested on Mathematica 12.2.